# Please make an Autodesk inventor tag and tag the inventor questions with it

Tags: support, tags

I want to ask an Autodesk Inventor question, but there is no such tag. Can someone please create a [autodesk-inventor] tag?

These two questions would need it:
[Installing Autodesk Inventor 11 Pro on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/237976/installing-autodesk-inventor-11-pro-on-windows-7)
and https://superuser.com/questions/387167/recording-drive-constraint-in-autodesk-inventor-2008-produces-black-screen.

As you can see, I have not yet 300 rep and I can't create a new tag. Someone, please make a new tag!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, [autodesk-inventor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autodesk-inventor) made and tagged three questions with it.

Comment: Woohoo! Soon to be 4. Thanks!